# Swing with Spring using annotation besa mapping

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-mvc

I am going to develop Desktop application using Swing, Spring framework and Hibernate. I want to map POJO by using annotation. I develop a code But I don't know where is going wrong...Here is my application's snap.

POJO:

```
@Table(name = "emp_master", schema = "test")
public class EmpMaster extends Model {
    private Integer empId;
    private String empName;
    private Double salary;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 131089, scale = 0)
    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
```

My main GUI Class:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {       
        String[] contextPaths = new String[]{"ApplicationContext.xml"};
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPaths);
```

this class contain button by clicking button I want to save record. The code under actionListener for button :

```
private IEmpMasterService empMasterService;
//getter setter for empMasterService//

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
        String name = jTextField1.getText();
        String salary = jTextField2.getText();
        EmpMaster empMaster = new EmpMaster();
        empMaster.setEmpName(name);
        empMaster.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(salary));  
 //at this line I get error NullPointerException     
        InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> response = getEmpMasterService().maintainEmpMaster(empMaster);         
    }
```

`IEmpMasterService` is an interface that contain id, name, salary.
in Pojo-def.xml:

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org" /> 
<import resource="datasource.xml" />
       <bean id="mainFrame" class="org.UI.EmpManager">
        <property name="title"> <value>Spring Example</value></property>            
    </bean>     
    <bean id="empManager" class="org.UI.EmpManager">
        <property name="empMasterService" ref="empMasterServiceImpl"></property>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="empMasterServiceImpl" class="org.service.EmpMasterService">
        <property name="empMasterDAO" ref="empMasterDAOTarget"></property>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="empMasterDAOTarget" class="org.DAO.EmpMasterDAO">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="matrixHibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>
```

I have created all service class and dao class properly also I configured datasource.xml and that working in separate project but i am getting error in main GUI class at line `getEmpMasterService()`: `NullPointerException`.
I think something wrong in mapping interface to implementer class can any one show me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The information which you provided from that I think , one of the reason can be , in Pojo-def.xml file Id of EmpMasterService is "**empMasterServiceImpl**" but in save record code EmpMasterService service having object name as "**empMasterService**". 
Hence it is not able to set object of EmpMasterService.

Comment: thanks for reply, empMasterService is an instance of IEmpMasterService which is a Interface and that referring to EmpMasterServiceImpl that implementing that interface by reference id empMasterServiceImpl. I know the problem is in Pojo-def.xml but it's something different.